# As a contractor, TurboTax Business-and-Home or Basic?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, software, contractor

At what point is it worth it to use TurboTax's Business and Home package ($99) over the Basic package($35)?

I worked as an independent contractor for a living last year, and I don't suspect there'll be many deductions I can write off, but I don't know. I work 50% of the time from home.

Should I invest in the more expensive package - will it help me avoid paying much more in the long run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you file state tax returns, you shouldn't buy Basic. Ever. Your choice is probably between the "Premier" version and the "Business and Home" version. Price difference is insignificant ([I have a comparison on my blog](http://www.littleadvisor.com/archives/1295), including short descriptions as to who might find each version useful the most). The prices have gone down significantly, since when I wrote the article, its cheaper now.